# Mod_wsgi mirror link

Tags: python, download, hyperlink, mod-wsgi, mirror

I can't download `mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so` from  google.because google banned my country IP , is there any place to download it ? i can not find any mirror link